# Easy way to show that punctured disk is not homeomoprhic to a disk

Tags: general-topology

So is there any easy way to show that $B(x,r)$ and $B(x,r)\backslash\{x\}$ are not homeomorphic?

Comment: One deformation retracts to a point, the other a circle, which does not deformation retracts to a point

Comment: Almost the same as Justin's: every continuous $S^1\to B(x,r)$ is homotopic to a constant map; with the punctured disk this is not the case.

Comment: Is your disk $B(x,r)$ considered open or  closed?

Comment: Thanks, we haven't covered retractions but I see how it works. @ChristianBlatter, my $B(x,r)$ is open. We denote closed balls by B with a bar on top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In $B:=B({\bf 0},1)\subset{\mathbb R}^2$ any simple closed loop $\gamma$ bounds a domain $\Omega\subset B$ such that $\bar\Omega=\Omega\cup\gamma$ is compact. (This is Jordan's curve theorem.) But in $\dot B:=B({\bf 0},1)\setminus\{{\bf 0}\}$ there are simple loops which do not bound such an $\Omega\subset \dot B$.